# How to get the latest DATE out of a Subject [ActionScript-3]

Tags: actionscript-3, date, forum

This one is a bit of a twister, i'm designing a Forum and i have three classes

- Subject

  Topic

  Post

Subject has a list of topics, and topic has a list of posts.
Post has an attribute called date, which of course is of type Date.
I want to be able to get in each subject, the most recent post Date, so in other words for each subject i have to check each post of each topic and save the most recent date.
My idea was to create a new list with all the posts, and then, some how order the list by date and show the first post.

Sorry about the really bad explaining.. Hope you understood correctly

EDIT:
This is what i have so far

```
 private function getLastPost(subject:Subject):String{
            var s:String;
            var post:Post = null;
            for each (var topic:Topic in subject.topics) 
            {
                for each (var p:Post in topic.posts) 
                {
                    if(post == null){
                        post = p;
                    }else{
                        if(post.date.valueOf() < p.date.valueOf()){
                            post = p;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            s = Utils.formatDate(post.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:NN:SS') + " by " + post.user.username;
            return s;
```

Comment: Question : Why do that client-side ? Would'nt it be easier to do it serverside ?

Comment: @Aralicia I'm not the person that decides that, im just the designer and all i have is a list of subjects, believe me i would love to just be able to do a ORDER BY... ^-^

Comment: okay. And what is your issue ? I don't see anything incorrect in your code.

Comment: @Aralicia Yeah turns out that the code above wasn't the problem, do i deleate the question now i have solved it or what? im new to this.

Comment: @GaryPerry, you can post an answer to your own question.  Since your code is working properly, I'd post that and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this at `Subject` creation time pretty easily.  Add a private `lastPost` variable to it, and then simply set that variable every time a new post is added to any `Topic`.